# Linux - How can I insert full contents of file1.txt into file2.txt at line number 4

Tags: linux, bash, text

I have two text files, insert.txt & 0282.ini

Contents of insert.txt

```
 3=6
 4=9750
 5=10600
 6=11700
```

Contents of 0282.ini

```
[SATTYPE]
1=0282
2=28.2E
```

How can I insert full contents of insert.txt into 0282.ini at line number 4 so the resulting file will look as follows: Please note there is more contents in this file so I do not want to insert it to the end of the file..

```
[SATTYPE]
1=0282
2=28.2E
3=6
4=9750
5=10600
6=11700
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '4r insert txt' 0282.ini
```

Add an `-i` option to write the results back to the ini file instead of just printing to standard output.

Comment: I tried that adding file locations `sed -i'4r /var/DVBViewerTransponders/details/insert.txt' /var/DVBViewerTransponders/0282.ini` but I got `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: extra characters after command`

Comment: Ignore last comment, I was missing a space after -i, working perfectly now

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '3r f1' f2

cat f2
[SATTYPE]
1=0282
2=28.2E
3=6
4=9750
5=10600
6=11700
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly but in this case a backup was not necessary as the original file can be created easily, I will keep this method in mind for other scripts.. thankyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
cat <(head -n $[4 - 1] 0282.ini) insert.txt <(tail -n +4 0282.ini)
```

or

```
{ head -n $[4 - 1] 0282.ini; cat insert.txt; tail -n +4 0282.ini; }
```